# How to cat a file twice in one pipline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am curious as to how to cat a file twice in a row using a pipeline that begins with:

```
cat file |
```

What would follow the pipe so that the contents of "file" would be printed twice in a row?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean twice in a row, or each line repeated, or what? You should [edit] your question to explain exactly what you want, showing us a small example.

Comment: What's the use-case?  Is `cat file file` sufficient to solve the actual problem?

Comment: Apologies for not being specific, I'm afraid it must begin with "cat file | ". The contents of file should be printed twice in a row, thank you

Comment: If it must begin with `cat file |` then this would also work: `cat file | cat file file`

Comment: The requirement to start with `cat file |` seems totally arbitrary and is basically being ignored in that pipeline, creating two sub-shells, calling `cat` twice and reading the contents of the file three times. The only sensible answer that has been provided is `cat file file`. I guess you could use `cat file | cat - file` if you really wanted...

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the alternative method. Honestly this is an academic question hehe, so the arbitrary nature of it is understandable

Comment: `cat` is for concatenating. If you only `cat` a single file you're doing something wrong and probably should replace `cat file | cmd` with `cmd < file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a `cat`...

You could do this with :

```
cat file file
```

If `file` contained the text <kbd>hello world</kbd>

The output would be:

> hello world
>   hello world

Another way to do this with the same results with be:

```
cat file <(cat file)
```

If it must begin with `cat file |` then this would also work:

```
cat file | cat file file
```

Or you could even do:

```
cat file | cat - file
```

However a more interesting way of doing it would be with [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) which is a pipe fitting. From the BSD General Commands Manual:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

So you could then do:

```
cat file | tee /dev/tty
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your last pipeline was exactly what I was looking for! I will accept your answer when the two minute time limit expires

Comment: Just so the first cat is not completely wasted, how about `cat file | cat - file`

Answer (score 1):

To me,

```
cat file | cat file file
```

does not seem to satisfy the spirit of the question.  I would go with something like:

```
cat file | tee /dev/tty
```